# Router settings page

Tags: windows, google-chrome, router, network-connection

I'm having problems to enter the router settings page.
I've already checked with 'ipconfig' that the address is the right one, and it is 192.168.1.1
I'm having problems only with my windows 10 pc, because with my smartphone I can access it with no problems.
I've tried it with chrome and after entering the user and the password it says "The webpage at http://192.168.1.1/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address."
I've also tried with microsoft edge and, after the log in it gives me a blank page.

How can I solve it? I've already tried to unplug the modem but no results.

Answer (score 0):

Reset to factory settings, and follow the directions for the router.

If that does not work - please edit your post to include the model of your router.